# Figure aligning with numbering Fig. 2a and 2b

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, diagrams, subfloats

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat*
\begin {center}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.68]{LA.eps}
\caption{\small load curve}
%\label{fig 2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin {center}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.68]{1.eps}
\caption{\load curve}
%\label{fig 2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat*
\begin {center}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.68]{LA.eps}
\caption{\small load curve}
%\label{fig 3}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat*
\begin {center}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.68]{LA.eps}
\caption{\small load curve}
%\label{fig 3}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although, figures size are same, however, I want to align Fig 2a with 2b and similarly with 3a and 3b even if some text exists between them(2a 2b)and (3a 3b). Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please tell us how the `\load` macro is defined. More importantly, your code would appear to produce two graphs, not four as is shown in the screenshot you posted. It's thus going to provide advice related to your question. Please edit your posting to create code that somewhat resembles the screenshot.

Comment: you forgot on preamble of your document ... please ad it.

Comment: Kindly help me out Mico and Zarko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessing, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

above I use `demo` option for included graphics which align perfect. However, your actual images can have some spurious white space which make troubles at aligning. This you can test with enclosing `includegraphics{...}` in `\fbox`.

Your code is quite complicated. The same figure numbering ind image positioning I obtain with use of `subfigure` and added changes of caption and numbering style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{Fig.~\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for simulating text in document

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{LA.eps}
\caption{load curve}
\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{l.eps}
\caption{load curve}
\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
%\caption{load curve}
%\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
    \lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{LA.eps}
\caption{load curve}
\label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.r5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{l.eps}
\caption{load curve}
\label{fig:2b}
    \end{subfigure}
%\caption{load curve}
%\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
after correcting labels and image size the compilation doesn't gives any warning not error  (of course you need to compile twice)!

Comment: Dear Zarko! CODE gives me error for package \usepackage[labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon]{subcaption} How can I run this ......................

Comment: Hm, MWE is tested and gives provided image without any error. Only five warnings regarding multiply-defined labels (I didn't bother with them). Do you change something?

Comment: NO Zarko bro I didn't change anything but it gives error every time.

Comment: Check your LaTeX installation (packages),  if they ares up-to-date.  MWE as is in answer works without any errors , warning or bad boxes. to say more, I need to see log file/error messages.